# apt-get finds nothing to upgrade after 1 month? (Willy 15.10)

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, 15.10

That's something I can't believe: 1 month after the last `apt-get upgrade`, I log back on that server of mine, running Ubuntu 15.10.
Of course, I `sudo apt-get update`...
Everything is fine, all repos reachable. Good!
Launching `sudo apt-get upgrade`...
**`0 upgraded, 0 installed, 0 removed, 0 not upgraded`**

(translated from french)

WTF?

1 month and nothing to update?
That's a bit too weird to even be plausible!
Can anyone relate?
Is there something wrong with my setup?

Here is my sources.list file

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                            OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                             #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                           UNOFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                            #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


###### 3rd Party Binary Repos

## Java
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu wily main

## Old Java
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu vivid main

## Steam
deb [arch=i386] http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
```

Comment: we do not support end of life versions. please install 16.04. That will also fix your problem.

Comment: never mind wrong page

Comment: OK, I've added a 15.10 tag to make things clear. 16.04 will fix THIS problem, but will create others that I don't need (no time to deal with that).

Answer (score 1):

15.10 reached its end of life date in July.

That means that all default repositories were frozen and many PPAs have abandoned support for 15.10.

It makes sense that there haven't been any upgrades for your release, since none have been built for it.

You need to [upgrade to 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) or manually upgrade packages using DEB files.

Comment: That escalated quickly!  
The problem is that 16.04 still have issues with, for instance, X2go...
I do **not** want to get into more trouble: I just want to keep my software up-to-date without upgrading the OS!
Please, don't tell me the only option is to deal with new issues as soon the EOL is reached!

Comment: @Pylou you can't get package updates normally when a release goes EOL. Canonical freezes the repositories, so no new packages can be uploaded. PPA maintainers tend to move away as well, since they also lose any support the might get keeping packages up to date for that EOL release. If you're using an EOL release, you need to rely on DEB archives for updates and [Unix.se] for help.